# Using SSH folders as a directory for my local system?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Can someone suggest what keywords I should use to search online for "Using SSH folders as a directory for my local system?"?

I want some files on my system to interact with files on a SSH server I have access to.

Comment: Search for "sshfs".

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [mounting remote folder using SSH on Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu/):

> Connecting to a server across the internet is much more secure using
>   SSH. There is a way that you can mount a folder on a remote server
>   using the SSHFS service.
>
> There are quite a few steps that you’ll have to follow, so get ready
>   and open a terminal window.
>
> First we’ll install the module:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sshfs
> ```
>
> Now we will use the modprobe command to load it
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe fuse
> ```
>
> We’ll need to set up some permissions in order to access the
>   utilities. Replace  with your username.
>
> ```
> sudo adduser <username> fuse
>
> sudo chown root:fuse /dev/fuse
>
> sudo chmod +x /dev/fusermount
> ```
>
> Since we’ve added ourselves to a user group, we need to logout and
>   back in at this point before we continue.
>
> Now we’ll create a directory to mount the remote folder in. I chose to
>   create it in my home directory and call it remoteserv.
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/remoteserv
> ```
>
> Now we have the command to actually mount it. You’ll be prompted to
>   save the server key and for your remote password.
>
> ```
> sshfs <username>@<ipaddress>:/remotepath ~/remoteserv
> ```
>
> Now you should be able to cd into the directory and start using it as
>   if it was local.
>
> ```
> geek@ubuntuServ:~/remoteserv$ ls -l
> total 16
> drwxr-xr-x 1 951247 155725 4096 2006-12-13 13:30 howtogeek.com
> drwxr-sr-x 1 root root 4096 2006-09-11 06:45 logs
> drwx—— 1 951247 155725 4096 2006-08-11 16:09 Maildir
> drwxrwxr-x 1 951247 155725 4096 2006-10-29 02:34 scripts
> ```

[Another source of information about SSH-FS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)